# Arranging data from an array to an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of data that is `["Bet:W:2:23:, "Bet:P:6:2", "Bet:W:5:3"]`.

[0] Bet $23 on #2 to win
[1] Bet $2 on #6 to place etc

How can I arrange the data so I can add the bets to a pool and then divide the pool amongst everyone who backed the winner?

I have tried iterating through and separating on the ':'. That means I can create the pool of bets, but it means I lose the link between the bets and the horse they bet on. I assume in order to maintain this connection I would need to create an object, but I have not been able to work out how to do it.

Comment: How will the result look?

Comment: This question is too broad. Start with something simpler like how to create an object with properties like `{bet:'win', id:'2', value: 23}`, then work on whatever distribution algorithm you want.

Comment: It sounds like you need an object for each bet like: [{Bet:23,
  Who:2,
  Result: Win},
  { Bet:2,
    Who:6,
    Result: Place
  }]

Comment: Unfortunately I have to start with the data how it is. I would like it to end up like [{Bet:23, Who:2, Result:Win}]. It is arranging it to look something like that that is where I am having trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
const bets = ["Bet:W:2:23", "Bet:P:6:2", "Bet:W:5:3"].map(b => {
    const bet = b.split(':');
    return {
        type: bet[1],
        number: bet[2],
        amount: parseInt(bet[3], 10)
    };
});
```

Once your data is in an easier to use form you can do other useful things like finding the pool amount using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
const pool = bets.reduce((sum, bet) => sum + bet.amount, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to define the objects using json, and create an object array. Typically you would follow this format:

```
var betPool = []; //defines empty object array for the betting pool
```

then for each bet you would construct something like this using key:value pairs for each bet, the push it to the array(this is the json notation that you were probably trying to achieve in your example)

```
{ amount: 'this.value', horse: 'this.number', condition:'this.condition' }
```

using that format, you should be able to access your betPool using a forEach() or .each method to parse the data appropriately using its key.

Let me know if you require further elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want your data to do 2 things: track the total betting pool, and be able to retrieve all bets (with betters) from any particular horse (like at payout time). You can custom make an object to do this.

```
var raceObj = {pool: 0};
```

Then iterate through adding a property for each horse. For example, from the array `['Bet:W:5:120','Bet:P:5:25','Bet:W:5:40','Bet:W:8:15']` we'd like the object:

```
{
    pool: 200,
    '5': {
        W: [120, 40],
        P: [25]
    },
    '8': {
        W: [15],
        P: []
    }
}
```

You can build up this object by iterating over the array like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var result = /^Bet:(W|P):([0-9]+):(.+)$/.exec(arr[i]);
    var type = result[1];
    var horse = result[2];
    var bet = parseInt(result[3]);

    raceObj.pool += bet;
    if (!raceObj.hasOwnProperty(horse)) {
        raceObj[horse] = {W: [], P: []};
    }
    raceObj[horse][type].push(bet);
}
```

I may not have exactly anticipated your needs, but I feel like if you these calculations just once then building a really customized object is a great option in javascript.